# Code formatter that can handle complex column alignment

Tags: c++, formatter

I am experimenting with some code beautifiers. So far, `clang-format` is my favourite. However, there is one issue I cannot solve. I wanted to know if anybody knows any code formatters that can handle the following issue:

**Input:**

```
ar << CDOMAttrName("RuntimeModus") << s.m_lRuntimeModus
    << CDOMAttrName("InstanzName") << s.m_sName
    << CDOMAttrName("LoginName") << s.m_sLoginName
    << CDOMAttrName("BenutzerNr") << s.m_nBenutzerNr;

ar[abc] = test(2, 33, 32);
ar[abcde] = test(2, 33, 32);
ar[abcd] = test(21, 333, 32);
ar[abcdefgh] = test(22,  33, 32);
ar[abcdefgh] = ee;
```

**Output:**

```
ar  << CDOMAttrName( "RuntimeModus" ) << s.m_lRuntimeModus
    << CDOMAttrName( "InstanzName"  ) << s.m_sName
    << CDOMAttrName( "LoginName"    ) << s.m_sLoginName
    << CDOMAttrName( "BenutzerNr"   ) << s.m_nBenutzerNr;

ar[abc     ] = test( 2,  33, 32);
ar[abcde   ] = test( 2,  33, 32);
ar[abcd    ] = test(21, 333, 32);
ar[abcdefgh] = test(22,  33, 32);
```

For code blocks, the brackets alignment and comma separated arguments should be in the same "column".

Comment: Grammatical fixes

Comment: This formatting requires from formatter to look ahead of what is being formatted to decide on proper format. I'm fairly certain there is no such formatter. Viable alternative would be to disable formatting for certain lines an leave it to user to format them as they wish.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs: <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp`<kbd>RETURN</kbd>`\(,\)]`<kbd>RETURN</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd>.

Comment: No, I am talking about an universal code formatter that formats a complete file condifering certain rules... Regex is a nice thing, but I looking for a formatter that acepts a genric rule for that and detects blocks automatically